# Custom ImageMagick scripts on Rails (Paperclip ?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip

I would like to use some of these scripts: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/ for processing images uploaded to my Rails app. How can I achieve it? Can I set it up in Paperclip somehow or need to write some custom code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paperclip provides a way to write your own image processor, which primarily make use of the command line tools provided by imagemagick and the like.

Since the scripts you link to above are all command line tools, it will be fairly trivial to write a processor to use these.

Resources:

- [Railscast #182](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) uses a custom processor to do cropping.
- The [default thumbnail processor](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb) of Paperclip provides good documentation on how your own processors can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider CarrierWave instead of Paperclip. It's easier to customize the image processing behavior with CarrierWave and RMagick.

The Railscast about CarrierWave is an excellent starting point:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads